# Two simultaneous connections under OS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ethernet

Is it possible to have a wired and a wifi connection established at the same time (under OS X) and define which services should use each connection?

For example:

- Connect to my Raspberry Pi via wired connection (SSH) using a "169.254..." address
- Connect to the Internet via wifi

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely connect to several networks at the same time.

You can also prioritize them. For example when both interfaces can connect to the Internet; upon loading a website, OS X  will try to use the interface with the highest priority first, then tries the other interfaces in descending order.

You can however not define on application level which interface should be used. But I don't really see a practical use case for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mechanisms that determine which interface is used.

First, OSX checks the ip address you want to reach and selects those interfaces that can be used to reach that address. This is done using the ip address, network mask and networking routing tables. If your Pi can only be reached using one interface, OSX automatically uses that interface.

Second, you can prioritize the networking interfaces. An elaborate guide can be found [here](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/network-interface-service-order-os-x/). Go to System preferences > Network, select the gear icon at the bottom of the interface list and select "Set Service Order..." Here, you can prioritize the interfaces.

In direct response to your question: no, you can't prioritize interfaces *per service*.

Comment: Couldn't you edit the routing table to control which IP addresses are accessed via which interface? That's not quite per-application interface control, but it would let you specify, for example, that `169.254/16` addresses go over the WiFi and everything else go over wired.

Comment: Yes, that's definately possible.